Reduce a multidimensional array of unknown depth to an indexed array with associative rows
I have a multidimensional array with indeterminant depth and need to reduce it to a 2d array (an indexed array of associative rows).
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "level" => 0
    "email" => "bexcailimited1@gmail.com"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "id" => 4
      "level" => 1
      "email" => "bexcailimited3@gmail.com"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 5
        "level" => 2
        "email" => "bexcailimited4@gmail.com"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:3 [▼
          "id" => 6
          "level" => 3
          "email" => "bexcailimited5@gmail.com"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "level" => 0
    "email" => "bexcailimited2@gmail.com"
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 7
    "level" => 0
    "email" => "bexcaitest@gmail.com"
  ]
  5 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "id" => 8
      "level" => 1
      "email" => "Test012@gmail.com"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 9
        "level" => 2
        "email" => "test03@gmail.com"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:3 [▼
          "id" => 10
          "level" => 3
          "email" => "test04@gmail.com"
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▼
          0 => array:3 [▼
            "id" => 11
            "level" => 4
            "email" => "test05@gmail.com"
          ]
          1 => array:1 [▼
            0 => array:3 [▼
              "id" => 12
              "level" => 5
              "email" => "test06@gmail.com"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]

I want to clean above array and get a 2d array like below (truncated):
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "level" => 2
    "email" => "example@example.com"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "level" => 5
    "email" => "example@example2.com"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "level" => 8
    "email" => "example@example3.com"
  ],
  ...
]

Ideally, I'd like the result to be ordered by id.
My project is running on Laravel8, if it matters.

To ensure that your associative subarrays are not deconstructed while flattening, only spread arrays which are not indexed.  Wrap $row inside of a parent array so that when it is spread by ..., the original row of data is kept intact.
Sort the structure after it is reduced to 2 levels.
Code: (Demo)
function flattenList(array $array): array
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        array_push($result, ...array_is_list($row) ? flattenList($row) : [$row]);
    }
    return $result;
}

$flatten2d = flattenlist($array);
usort($flatten2d, fn($a, $b) => $a['id'] <=> $b['id']);
var_export($flatten2d);


I tried to solve the problem after your comments and founds your answer is that, what i'm looking for. Thanks to stackoverflow and you.
